# Render emissive light of an object even when the object is behind another object in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, render, light

I using Unity 2022.3.14f1 and URP rendering.

I would like to render a light neon effect for an object which is under and other object in order to just see the emission like that : [image rendered in Blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrLW5.jpg)
I have first do this object in blender with like neon light between plane to have this neon effect.

I put my objects in Unity and I associated the "neon" mesh with a material with an emission in order to have a neon effect.

I would like to see the emissive light even when my object "neon" is behind an object.

I tried several techniques to always render my object with "Queue"="Overlay" for example but nothing works.

Do you have any possible solutions?

Thank you!

I have what I'm looking for but only when I see the object through the camera, otherwise it's as if the object was not rendered and therefore we don't see the broadcast. Below are two images showing my object with the "neon" behind the first plane and the other image showing the neon in front of the first plane which has many emissions which should be seen even if the shape of the neon is behind.
[neon shape object behind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQNKo.png) -
[neon shape object in front of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ErYT.png)

Comment: well the blender one looks like those side walls do the emission... today im currently not a fan of unity lighting - we had a falling out, but, if you need it to come through you cant have opaque, or you render it for webgl and it leaks more than a mains water pipe with a hole (my issue) but it wont do it how you want but it will leak..